# Data is getting misplaced on zlicking on the zoom optionsin timeline.js file-Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 icons which is on and off state

using timeline.js which has zoom in that.

When the page gets loaded for the first time on(green) and off(red) icon is placed perfectly
(on and off is based on time interval)
since it is not zommed it will be overlayed on eachother.(red overlyed by green )

once i use zoom it become vise versa.

here is my code

```
fixTimelineIcons: function() {
  var ticons = $('.timeline-event-icon');
  ticons.sort(function(a,b) {
      return (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : ((b.id > a.id) ? -1 : 0);
  }); 
  for(var i = 0; i<ticons.length; i++) {
      ticons[i].style.zIndex = (i+1);
  }
}
```

a.id =icon-t1-12 just an id
b.id =icon-t1-3 just an id

Can any one help on this please

Comment: Can you please post the HTML & CSS?

Comment: That is 3rd party library timeline.js